# fitnesse not able to refer external API's in Java?

Tags: java, classpath, fitnesse

fitnesse is not able to test my application. 
I am working on Java and have defined three things in the class path : 
1) path to fitnesse.jar 
2) path to another jar file(xstream.jar) which my code requires. (this jar is included in the build path of my project also). 
3) class path of my fixture class.

Fitnesse is showing "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream
" 
can anyone please help, this thing has really made my whole work stuck up !!!

Comment: FileNotFoundException, not a NoClassDefFoundError?

Comment: thanks to correct me daveb.. :)
exact error is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream

Comment: What's the exact classpath you're using?  And also, the platform you're on.

Comment: this is how i m specifying the classpath:
!path D:fitnesse.jar
!path D:poc\lib\xstream.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had recentley similar problems. My resolution was to set the correct working dir. I got this work with use of the followin start bat:

```
call java -DBaseDir=D:\MyBaseDir -DmyPath=D:\MyBaseDir\someSubDirs\bin -DmyLibraryPath="%PATH%;.;D:\MyBaseDir\someSubDirs\lib" -jar D:\MyBaseDir\Fitnesse\fitnesse.jar -d D:\MyBaseDir\Fitnesse\ -r MySuite -p 8080
```

Be aware of the start parameters: -d is used for the working dir. Perhaps this gives you some further idea where to look.

Answer (score 0):

It's not finding the xstream lib in your CLASSPATH, you'll need to double check that Fitnesse is picking that up.

Comment: how do i check it..
i m new to fitnesse and dont know much abt that..
this is how i m definig the classpaths:
!path D:fitnesse.jar
!path D:poc\lib\xstream.jar

Comment: Can you edit your question with the exact command line you are using, that way you can use the code formatting and we can see if you have any typos etc

Comment: ok.. here is a detailed description Martijn:
  1) In my fixture code, I am extending ColumnFixture 
  2) My fixture class will call my API. The API then interacts with an XML file, picks a property from there and then searches for the matching property in properties file.
  3) my Fixtures wiki page (the wiki table page in fitnesse), there i have defined the claspaths as mentioned above.

Comment: !path D:poc\lib\xstream.jar does not look correct to me, would it not be !path D:\poc\lib\xstream.jar

Comment: No Martijn, that does not make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the reason for your errors, but I got a good start with FitNesse by using [testifywizard](http://code.google.com/p/testifywizard/) to set up a testproject and copy the FitNesse bits afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how your classpath should be defined in FitNesse (note \ before poc):

```
!path D:\poc\lib\xstream.jar
```

Make sure you indeed have xstream.jar in D:\poc\lib folder. But you don't need to add fitnesse.jar in the classpath since it is already added by default by FitNesse framework.

After you execute your test, you can check the classpath used by FitNesse by clicking on 'Yellow Triangle' (if test fails) or 'Blue I' (if test succeeds) icon on top-right of your test wiki page.